# Embedded or referenced documents with mongoose Schema data?

Tags: mongoose, database-design, data-modeling, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am working on a group project using mongoDB and mongoose, where I intend to have three main pieces of data. A 'Users' collection, a collection of recipients(or contacts) associated to each individual user, and a collection of messages associated with each individual recipient. In other words each User will have a list of recipients and each Recipient will have a list of messages.
Is it better to structure the data into three separate models with references, or use one User document with an array of messages embedded in an array of recipients embedded in the user? Also how will the api routes differ for either data structure?

I have read the mongoose documentation about Schema modeling, references, and using .populate() but am just having trouble grasping the correct way to do this. I may just be over complicating the issue but if someone could provide a clearer explanation and provide some examples it would be appreciated.

I am expecting to be able to query the recipients of a logged in user, and when a recipient is selected to query only the messages associated to that recipient.